# Better way to convert JSON to arrays for graphing timeseries in C3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lodash, c3.js

I'm working on converting some JSON data into a format that will work for graphing a timeseries in C3, which takes an array of arrays as column input. I have my unique x values array, but I can't figure out a great way to get my y values. Once I get this done, I need to add y2 with numSold, but I think if I can solve this, I'll be able to figure that part out.

This is the final format I need for the data:

```
[
  ["x", "9-2-17", "9-4-17", "10-2-17"],
  ['item1-cost', 100, 150, 10],
  ['item3-cost', 200, null, 20],
  ...
]
```

There isn't a set number of dates or set number of items. It's whatever I read from the database. The item numbers aren't necessarily consecutive. We only care about graphing the data for items we have data for. But there won't be data for every date-item combination. When that happens, I need to insert a null to indicate that the item didn't have data for that date. Item numbers are 1-indexed.

I'm fine with using anything from lo-dash or D3 in addition to the plain JavaScript functions to solve this, but I'm trying to avoid hard to read code and inefficient code. I feel like others must have had a need for this and that there must be some sort of function like maybe a filter function that I should be using instead.

My current implementation is not as efficient  as I'd like and is a bit hard to read. I'm using the item number as an index and making a sparse array that I'll have to condense later. Here's the psudocode:

```
For every d object in data
  For the i index of d.date in uniqueDates
    If values[d.item] is undefined
      Fill values[d.item]] with null for uniqueDates.length
    Set values[d.item][i] to d.cost
Convert values to dense format for graphing
```

Here's a link to the Fiddle I'm playing with:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbkidd/q3r3moqu/

```
var data = [
  {date: '9-2-17', item: 1, cost: 100},
  {date: '9-2-17', item: 3, cost: 200},
  {date: '9-4-17', item: 1, cost: 150},
  /* '9-4-17' does not have an entry for item 3 so cost should be counted as null */
  {date: '10-2-17', item: 1, cost: 10},
  {date: '10-2-17', item: 3, cost: 20}
]

var uniqueDates = _.uniq(_.flatMap(data, 'date'));
uniqueDates.unshift('x');

var values = [];
values.push(uniqueDates);

function getLabel(index) {
  return 'item' + index + '-' + 'cost';
}

for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
  var i = _.indexOf(uniqueDates, data[d].date);
  if (data[d].item !== undefined) {
    var item = data[d].item;
    if (values[item] === undefined) {
        values[item] = _.fill(Array(uniqueDates.length), null);
        values[item][0] = getLabel(item);
    }
    values[item][i] = data[d].cost;
    }
}

function checkIfUndefined(x) {
    return (x !== undefined);
}

function sparseToDense(data) {
  return data.filter(checkIfUndefined);
}

values = sparseToDense(values);
```

Comment: Note that converting from sparse to dense isn't entirely necessary; we can just fill with empty arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295727/how-to-use-sparse-arrays-with-c3-charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued by this problem and came up with a first version. It's a little different than yours but here it is. I will note that I didn't try to sort the dates or rename the items to something useful but those can be added.

```js
var data = [
 {date: '9-2-17', item: 1, cost: 100},
  {date: '9-2-17', item: 3, cost: 200},
  {date: '9-4-17', item: 1, cost: 150},
  /* '9-4-17' does not have an entry for item 3 so cost should be counted as null */
  {date: '10-2-17', item: 1, cost: 10},
  {date: '10-2-17', item: 3, cost: 20},
  {date: '10-3-17', item: 2, cost: 2000}
]

// utility functions
const product = (...sets) =>
  sets.reduce((acc, set) =>
    _.flatten(acc.map(x => set.map(y => [ ...x, y ]))),
    [[]]);

// the meat and potatoes
const builder = lookup => pairs => pairs.reduce((agg, [item, date]) => {
   const out = _.cloneDeep(agg);
   const value = _.get(lookup, [date, item, 'cost'], null);
   const evalue = _.get(out, date, []);
   evalue.push(value);
   _.set(out, date, evalue);
   return out;
}, {})

// setup data structures for searching
const byDateByItem = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'date'), x => _.keyBy(x, 'item'));    
const items = _.uniq(data.map(x=>x.item));
const dates = _.uniq(data.map(x=>x.date));

// create all posibilities
const pairs = product(items, dates);
// populate possibilities with values
const hash = builder(byDateByItem)(pairs);
// put keys with values in their respective lists
const p = _.toPairs(hash).map(_.flatten);
// smash data into a matrix type thing
const table = [['x',...items], ...p];
// flip the table on it's side (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
const out = _.zip(...table);
console.log('out', out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, this is pretty cool. I wonder how it would hold up in performance for a lot of data.

Comment: Initial jsperf.com results have my original implementation as faster, but I'm not sure that'll hold true if the arrays are huge.

Comment: I bet it's not blazing fast but more than likely you wouldn't use JS if you want blazing fast perf. The majority of the time you will be able to change other things before needing to make micro optimizations to code.

Comment: You could likely pull out the `cloneDeep` part to save some time quickly but this code is written to maximize for maintainability and testability over speed.