# How to use sparse arrays with C3 charts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts, c3.js

For graphing in C3, we can give it column data, which is an array of arrays with each array being a different line on the chart like in this [C3 docs example.](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html) But is there a way to have that column data sparse? I'm getting an error when I try that, although I'm not sure if there's a workaround I don't know about.

If not, is there a better way to convert between sparse and dense arrays than a filter function like what I have?

https://jsfiddle.net/dbkidd/majx8byn/

```
var columnData = []

var entry1 = ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250];
var entry2 = ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25];

columnData[0] = entry1;
columnData[3] = entry2;
console.log('columnData - sparse format', JSON.stringify(columnData));

function checkIfUndefined(x) {
    return (x !== undefined);
}

function sparseToDense(data) {
  return data.filter(checkIfUndefined);
}

/* If you comment out this sparseToDense conversion, it breaks
 * with the following error:
 * c3.js:5403 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
*/
columnData = sparseToDense(columnData);
console.log('columnData - dense format', JSON.stringify(columnData));

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: columnData,
        axes: {
            data1: 'y',
            data2: 'y2'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        y2: {
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use empty array as entry value. This works ok:

```
[["data1",30,200,100,400,150,250],[],[],["data2",50,20,10,40,15,25]]
```

And modify your filtering function to skip arrays without length:

```
function checkIfNull(x) {
    return (x.length);
}
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/majx8byn/5/)

Comment: Nice! Thanks -- I'll do that